# How to control retention over aggregate state store and changelog topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My use case is the following:
Orders are flowing into an activation system via a topic. I have to Identify changes for records of same key. I compare the existing value with the new value using the aggregate function and output an event that points out the type of change identified i.e. DueDate Change.

The key is a randomly generated number and the number of unique keys is pretty much unbound. The same key will be reused in case the ordering system push a revision to an existing order.

The code has been running for a couple month in production but the state store and changelog topic are growing and there is a concern of space usage. I would like to have records expire after 90 days in the state store. I read about ways to apply a time based retention on state store and it looks like windowing the aggregation is a way of achieving that.

I understand that windowed aggregation are only available for tumbling and hopping window. Sliding window is available for join operation only.

Tumbling window wouldn't work in this case because I would have windows for 0-90, 90-180 and I wouldn't be able to identify an update on day 92 for a record that came in on day 89 (they wouldn't share the same window).

Now the only other option is hopping window.

`TimeWindows timeWindow = TimeWindows.of(90days).advanceBy(1day).until(1day);`

The problem is that I'll have to persist and update 90 windows. When the stream starts, 90 windows will be created 0-90, 1-91, 2-92, 3-93 etc. If I have a retention of 1 day on the windows, the window 0-90 will be cleaned up on day 91.

Now lets say on day 90 I get an update. Correct me if I'm wrong but my understanding is that I will have to update 90 windows and my state store will be quite large by that time because of all the duplicates. Maybe this is where I'm missing something. If a record is present in 90 windows, is it physically written on disk 90 times?

In the end all I need is to prevent my state store and changelog topic from growing indefinitely. 90 days of historical data is sufficient to support my use case.

Would there be a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to not use the DSL but the Processor API with a windowed state store. A windowed state store is just a key-value store with expiration. Hence, you can use it similar to a key-value store -- you only provide an additional timestamp that will be used to expire data eventually.